# LongListSelector Foreground Color

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Have been searching through here with no luck, Pretty simple problem, On my emulator all font colors are white (which is what I want).

Testing on a device the fonts are all black now, I have managed to change this by setting the foreground colors on the elements however I am unable to do so on the longlistselector through code.

This works for me:

```
longListSelector.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
```

However this has no effect:

```
longListSelector.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
```

Any other way I can attempt to set the text color on the longlistselector?

Comment: Do you have a DataTemplate for your LongListSelector? You might need to set the foreground color of the TextBlock inside of the DataTemplate, for example, and not for the LongListSelector.

Answer (score 0):

The reason foreground colors would be different would be because of the default style. PhoneAccentBrush changes based on if your "phone" is set to have a white background or a black one.

The reason why your longListSelector.Foreground is not working may be because the phoneaccentbrush is set on the items inside the longlistselector from a style?

Comment: Just after testing and this does seem to be the case, However I only create the basic longlistselector through code, I dont specify a style anywhere. Is there an example of how I can overwrite the phoneaccentbrush through code? Thanks